# How do I enable VRSS (Virtual Receive Side Scaling) for a Windows VM without relying on Enable-NetAdapterRSS?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I have a problem that running the powershell `Enable-NetAdapterRSS` to enable VRSS (Virtual Receive Side Scaling) command is failing in our scenario, and I suspect we may have some kind of runtime-dependency or constraint which may be hard to work around.

Is there another way I can try, like using WMI directly? I found a bunch of network adapter related WMI classes like Win32_NetworkAdapter but most of them do not mention VRSS anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the pieces of info I need! In powershell you can do:

```
(Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetAdapterRssSettingData -Namespace "root\StandardCimv2").Enabled
```

to view the current state, and

```
(Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetAdapterRssSettingData -Namespace "root\StandardCimv2").Enable()
```

to enable VRSS (if you're admin). (Of course you can also do it with C# using `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`, or use any other language with WMI support...)